# Spring ConfigurationProperties file - giving a default value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a ConfigurationProperties class looks something like this (stripped out to show what i need)

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "something")
@Configuration
@Data
public class SomethingProps {

    private OtherProps otherProps;
}
```

```
@Data
public class OtherProps {

    private boolean enabled = true;
}
```

When I provide this in my application.yml file everything works fine

```
something:
   otherProps: true
```

But when I don't provide otherProps at all in the yml file then i get a null pointer exception when autowiring OtherProps in a constructor. My expectation is that it would default to true, i have tried annotating with @NotNull

Comment: You need to create an instance of the `OtherProps` as well, you need to initialize the `otherProps` field. This is also how it is done in the Spring Boot own property classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize `OtherProps`.

```
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "something")
    @Configuration
    @Data
    public class SomethingProps {
    
        private OtherProps otherProps=new OtherProps();
    }


    @Data
    public class OtherProps {
    
        private boolean enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you import your config class instead of creating an object.

For eg.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "something")
@Configuration
@Import({OtherProps.class})
@Data
public class SomethingProps {

}
```

and your OtherProps class will be like this,

```
@Data
public class OtherProps {

    private boolean enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, the only solution so far that has worked is creating the object, its not that neat so would prefer something like this but doesn't seem to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = { OtherProps.class })
@Data
public class SomethingProps {


}
```

and then

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "something")
public class OtherProps {

private boolean enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

actually you can use @Value annotation as alternative

```
@Value("x.y.z:default_value")
private boolean isEnabled;
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following approach:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class SomethingProperties {
   private OtherProps otherProps = new OtherProps();
   // getters/setters/lombok generated whatever

   public static class OtherProps {
     private boolean enabled = true;
     // getters/setters/lombok generated whatever
   }
}


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomethingProps.class) 
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean 
   public SampleBean sampleBean(SomethingProps config) {
      return new SampleBean(config.getOtherProps().isEnabled());
   }
}
```